# In which field does this equation lies

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

It is well known that if $f(x)$ is irreducible then $$g(x) \bmod f(x) = g(\alpha)$$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$. I am  skeptical that can I write this equality $g(x) \bmod f(x) = g(\alpha)$ as on the left have side we have a polynomial and on the right hand side we have a field element.

Comment: This statement is badly garbled.  What do you mean by "**the** root of $f(x)$"?  Do you mean to say that $f(x)$ is just $x-\alpha$?

Comment: In a finite field generated by an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, there is a one-to-one correspondence between field elements and polynomials of degree less than $d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By division $\,\ g = q f + r\ $ for $\ r = g\bmod f$

so $\,\color{#c00}{f(\alpha) = 0}\,\Rightarrow g(\alpha) =  q(\alpha) \color{#c00}{f(\alpha)} + r(\alpha) = r(\alpha)$

Comment: my question is how are we saying that a field element is equal to a polynomial ?

Comment: @xyz You need to *evaluate* it at $\,x=\alpha\,$ as above.